# Troubles usb connecting/accessing internet on Beaglebone black

Tags: macos, ssh, beagleboneblack, ubuntu-16.04, beagleboard

So I am having problems serial connecting through usb on BeagleBone Black (BBB) and accessing the internet on BBB. When I first followed instruction on website about Getting Started...everything worked fine on my Mac and was able to see the BBB as a removable disk (and connect serially through the usb) and access the internet on it as well (ping and sudo apt-get worked).

**WHERE THE PROBLEMS STARTED**

I then changed distros from pre-installed Angstrom image and went to Ubuntu 16.04 booted on an micro SD card. I had problems initially burning the image but then installed it correctly. I then started using the USB to UART connector to serial connect since I found out it would be easier to use. This worked and I used this more than the usb serial connect. (I could still usb connect on windows however). Everything worked fine, even ping and apt-get when I had ethernet connected. I just installed LXDE as well.

**WHAT DOESN'T WORK AS OF NOW**

So now right after I installed LXDE to get a gui (and hopefully make things easier) I cannot access the internet (ping, apt-get, even share the network off my Mac).

1) *Nothing internet-related works*.

I try now to usb connect on my Mac and the BBB does not show up as a removable drive. Even Windows detects something connected but cannot install the drivers to detect it (even when I install drivers on beagle bone website, it still does not pick it up).

2) *USB serial connect stopped functioning*.

**WHAT DOES WORK**

I can still serial connect via the USB to UART connector. That is how I can still login.

1) *USB to UART serial connect works*.

The most weirdest of them all...I can ssh to 192.168.7.2 WHEN MY NETWORK SETTINGS HAS INTERNET SHARING DISABLED. (**When internet sharing is enabled to share my Mac's network, whether through ethernet or wifi, I cannot ssh to 192.168.7.2!**) when I type `ifconfig` on shell in putty terminal after I log into the BBB, the eth0 address shows as 192.168.1.231 WHEN I HAVE ETHERNET CABLE CONNECTED TO BBB. When I do not connect it, of course, no eth0 inet address shows. Another weird fact, I can ssh to 192.168.7.2 whenever internet sharing is off **AND/OR** 192.168.1.231 when ethernet cable is connected to BBB.

2) Ssh'ing to 192.168.7.2 works when internet sharing is disable and/or ssh'ing 192.168.1.231 works when ethernet cable is connected to BBB.

---

So after all that craziness and hours of trying to debug....any help on how to fix these problems???

---

***EDIT***

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
# Example to keep MAC address between reboots
#hwaddress ether DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE

# The secondary network interface
#auto eth1
#iface eth1 inet dhcp

# WiFi use: -> connmanctl

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
# Used by: /opt/scripts/boot/autoconfigure_usb0.sh
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.252
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

Comment: it should work if you connect the BBB Ethernet to a network that has a DHCP server and routing to the internet. If you want to do that over USB, it will be more complicated.

Comment: hmmm. But I can still connect via the UART debug connector. That has never stopped working since the first day I used it. The actual USB connection is what has stopped working. I can still ssh to 192.168.7.2 with or without ethernet connected to my router which plugs into my BBB. **The weird thing is, when I run `ifconfig` and ethernet is connected to BBB from my home router, I see an inet address of 192.168.1.231 which I can ssh to as well but still I cannot ping or do sudo-apt get because there is no internet connection.** Any advice

Comment: Check if it sets a default route (`ip route`) and if it sets the nameserver (`cat /etc/resolv.conf` should point either to your router, your ISP or 127.0.0.1).

Comment: This is the output of ip route: `default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.232  metric 100                            
192.168.7.0/30 dev usb0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.7.2` There is no output when I do `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: It points to my ISP

Comment: If there is no entry in resolv.conf, then this is the issue. Try `echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >/etc/resolv.conf`. That sets it to the Google name servers.

Comment: It says no file or directory when I echo and redirect. I tried manually to go to the file resolv.conf but there is none listed so I made one with that name but I get an error: `"/etc/resolv.conf" E166: Can't open linked file for writing Press ENTER or type command to continue`

Comment: See my edited question for interfaces file that my need to be edited!

Comment: if it says it's a link. then please check where it points to `ls -la /etc/resolv.conf`. You could always `rm -f /etc/resolv.conf` first. Though a proper fix might be preferable.

Comment: `ls -la /etc/resolv.conf -> /var/runs/connman/resolv.conf`. But when I try to navigate to that file, nothing exists. I tried to `cat /var/runs/connman/resolv.conf` but it says there is no file or directory that exists. I even tried `ls -a` on the directories and there is no resolv.conf. I made a resolv.conf in the /etc/ folder with `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and I still cannot ping

Comment: Can you ping: `192.168.1.254`, `8.8.8.8`. Also try a `traceroute` or `tracepath` to `8.8.8.8`